# Generar círculos cada 2 segundos

Tags: android, android-studio, hilos, canvas

quiero generar círculos cada 2 segundos, en este caso 5 pero no logro conseguirlo. En vez de crear un circulo cada 2 segundos espera 10 segundos y dibuja los 5 juntos. Cual es la falla? Gracias.

```
public class Juego extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

boolean isItOK = false;

Paint paint;
int CantidadDeEsferas = 5;
int radio, alto, ancho;

public Juego(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    paint = new Paint();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    for (int i=0; i<CantidadDeEsferas; i++) {

        Random r = new Random();
        alto = r.nextInt(canvas.getHeight());
        ancho = r.nextInt(canvas.getWidth());
        radio = r.nextInt(101 - 50) + 50;
        canvas.drawCircle(ancho, alto, radio, paint);
        isItOK = true;
        run();
    }
}

public void run(){
    int esperar_segundos = 2;
    while (isItOK == true){
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(esperar_segundos * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        isItOK = false;
    }
}
```